# Spring BeanCurrentlyInCreationException

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have the following java config class:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

    @Autowired
    private List<MyInterface> myInterfaces;

    @Bean
    public A a() {
        return new A();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        a().setProperty(myInterfaces);
    }
}
```

Each MyInterface implementation will have a dependency on bean A, which I assume is where this circular dependency is coming from; my expectation, however, was as follows:

1. This configuration class instantiates A and adds it to the application context
2. The implementations of MyInterface are successfully injected with bean A
3. The list of MyInterface implementations are injected into MyConfig
4. The @PostConstruct executes, setting myInterfaces on bean A

Can anyone shed some light on which of my assumptions is incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

You have a circular dependency in your code: remember that `MyConfig` is a bean as well so it needs to be instantiated and autowired. In order for it to be created, it needs to be injected with all available `MyInterface` instances, one of which requires bean `A`, which is created by an instance method of `MyConfig` and so on.

If you were to run in Spring Boot 1.4+, you would get this output:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

    The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌─────┐
|  interfaceImpl defined in file [/.../InterfaceImpl.class] 
↑     ↓
|  myConfig (field private java.util.List demo.MyConfig.myInterfaces)
└─────┘
```

You have two options :

- make `public A a() {` -> `public static A a() {` (thus not requiring bean A to be created by an instance method of `MyConfig`);
- make `myInterfaces` a `@Lazy` dependency (so that is actually populated only when accessed): e.g.

  ```
  @Autowired @Lazy
  private List<MyInterface> myInterfaces;
  ```